# How can I prove the following integral identity?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

The following equation is a solution of a convection-diffusion problem. I want to prove that the resultant solution is simplified to the initial condition when $\Delta t$ approaches zero. Consequently, I want to prove the following integral identity.

$$\lim_{\Delta t\ \rightarrow\ 0}\frac{1}{2 \Delta t} \int_{0}^\infty x\ F(x)\ e^ {-\frac{x^2 + r^2}{4 \Delta t}}\ I_0(\frac{x r}{2 \Delta t})\ {d}x = F(r)$$

where $F(r)$ is the initial solution of the problem whose solution is displayed by the LHS of the previous equation. $I_0$ is modified Bessel function of the first kind of zeroth order.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What is $I_0$? Is it a Bessel function?

Comment: It is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of zero order.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to address the definition of $I_0$! I guess that the proof will have something to do with the Dirac delta 'function' and its ['sifting' property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation).

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. The equation doesn't include Dirac delta function and this solution has not been obtained using it.

Comment: The Wikipedia page I linked in my comment tells that $$\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{1}{a \sqrt{\pi}} \exp -\frac{x^2}{a^2} = \delta (x).$$ Also, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \delta(x-a) dx = f(a).$$ It looks like what you want, but we need to fill the details in. Also, are you sure that its $4\Delta t$ in the denominator of the argument of the exponential, or is it $4\Delta t^2$?